# How to generate mediawiki-ready documentation from reflection and xml comments

Tags: c#, mediawiki, xmldocument, tooling

Could someone suggest a good workflow that,

- Independently on the number of
  disparate tools that could be
  required
- and how much manual work would have
  to be performed,

could allow me to incorporate my project documentation (reflection + xml comments) into mediawiki syntax, which I would then use to incorporate on my development team wikia?

Comment: One of the best questions ever asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is going to be some manual labor involved, but it should be doable using the resources outlined below.

My first thought was just doing some googling, by which I came across http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers.  All of these parsers seem to take data and convert it to XML, not from XML, also none of them are .NET based, which may not be super important in the long run if no coding had been involved.  Who knows though, there may be something here worth looking at.

Then I found http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps.  I figure if you can import data in an XML format then all you really need to know is what the schema is so that you can reformat your data in the appropriate way. The **best thing** is that this page has a link to http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:XML_Import_file_manipulation_in_CSharp, a C# example of how to work with Media Wiki XML Import files.  Given the example it seems like only a small step to create the classes required for generating the required xml from scratch and dumping your data in.  Here is a link to the official schema documentation: http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3.xsd.

Depending on whether you want to write PHP or not another option presents itself.  You could write an XMLTransform Extension, as talked about here: http://www.ehartwell.com/TechNotes/MediaWikiXmlExtension.htm.  This site seems to say that you could keep your XML in it's native format and write a custom XSL sheet to display the contents in the desired format.

Good luck!

Comment: Excellent, Patricker. This should help me get started and I can take it from here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sandcastle to create a webpage from your source code http://documentation.sandcastle.codeplex.com

You have to enable the XML generation of your projects in your project settings.
The generated XML can be used in sandcastle to generate some cool documentation for example as an webpage.

Comment: This is not what I asked, Marco. I'm perfectly aware of the tools to generate documentation from my source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), to [generate XML](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) and then process the resulting XML (XSLT or the tool[s] of your choice) into something suitable for your needs.

If you've installed [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), doxygen can use its `dot` tool to [generate various diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) as well. Here's an example (from the KDE docs) of a class hierarchy diagram generated by doxygen: http://api.kde.org/playground-api/graphics-apidocs/cirkuit/src/lib/html/inherits.html

Another, slight less flamboyant one (from IBM): http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUMemory.html

Comment: Dunno Nicholas, It gets me stuck where I am right now. And that is, how to move into mediawiki format.